# php getting count as per flags from text file

Tags: php, file-processing

I am making a log file which logs in the following manner:

```
[08-12-2016 22:59:38.000000] [Error] Testing
[08-12-2016 22:59:45.000000] [Error] Testing
[08-12-2016 23:03:37.000000] [warning] Testing
```

I am trying to make a function which can read total warning and total errors in log file. The following code works fine. The question is: Is there a better way to do this?

```
$file = file( $complete_filename );

$totalErrors = 0;
$totalWarnings = 0;

foreach($file as $rows) {

  if(strpos( $rows,  "[warning]")) $totalWarnings ++;
  if(strpos( $rows,  "[Error]"))   $totalErrors ++;

}

echo "$totalWarnings/$totalErrors";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like so: `echo $totalWarnings/$totalErrors;` ?

Comment: @Ivan Why? He is just outputting the numbers, not trying to divide them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for improvements to working code

Comment: @Sverri Oups, I though he wanted a ratio. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log files can get pretty large. The `file` function reads the entire file into memory. If the file is very large then PHP may run out of memory and you will get an error.

To avoid running out of memory you can use `fopen` to get a file handle and then read one line at a time using `fgets`:

```
$totalErrors = 0;
$totalWarnings = 0;

$fh = fopen($complete_filename, 'rb');

if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, "[Error]") !== false) {
            $totalErrors++;
        }
        if (strpos($line, "[warning]") !== false) {
            $totalWarnings++;
        }
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours and its working fine.  can you please elaborate why fopen() is better then file() that might help others too.

Comment: Reading the entire log file into memory will stop working when it gets too big to fit into memory. Reading one line at a time ensures that only a small amount of memory will be used.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you may allow in the error message, your approach may or may not yield more errors/warnings than there are actual log lines, because you're only looking for the substring match in each line. Such that a log line of `[08-12-2016 22:59:38.000000] [Error] Testing [warning]` yields both 1 error and 1 warning for a single line.

You could try using a regular expression instead to be more diligent.

```
$logResults = array_map(function($line) {
    if (preg_match('/\[.*\]\s\[(Error|warning)\]/', $line, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    }
}, file($logFileName));

$errors = array_filter($logResults, function($l) { return $l === 'Error'; });
$warnings = array_filter($logResults, function($l) { return $l === 'warning'; });

echo "Number of errors: $errors\n";
echo "Number of warnings: $warnings\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP function call `substr_count()` in order to count the number of string match inside a string.

```
$logs = file( $complete_filename );

$totalErrors = substr_count($logs, '[Error]');
$totalWarnings = substr_count($logs, '[warning]');

echo $totalWarnings . ' warnings and ' . $totalErrors . ' errors';
```